# Why are Python strings behaving funny?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I'm so confused... why/how is `a` different from `b`?! Why don't they print the same thing?

```
>>> a = '"'
>>> a
'"'
>>> b = "'"
>>> b
"'"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Neither on Python 2.7, nor 3.3.

Comment: No, I get False in the equality test.

Comment: @EmilIvanov: ah, yes, the equality test.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not. The first string is comprised of a double quote, whereas the second string is comprised of a single quote. Clearly, `'` and `"` are not equal.

Comment: ooops I messed up the last statement LOL, sorry, just fixed it. Not sure why I added that, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Mehrdad, I do not understand the question, the strings are **different**, why should they print the same thing?

Comment: @phant0m: yeah, was not paying attention to that part. I thought everyone was talking about the quoting presentation not being different. :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strings are not presented differently. Their presentation is just adjusted to avoid having to quote the contained quote. Both `'` and `"` are legal string literal delimiters.

Note that the *contents* of the string *are* very different. `"` is not the same string as `'`; `a == b` is (patently) `False`.

Python would have to use a `\` backslash for the `"` or `'` character otherwise. If you use *both* characters in a string, then python is forced to use quoting:

```
>>> '\'"'
'\'"'
>>> """Tripple quoted means you can use both without escaping them: "'"""
'Tripple quoted means you can use both without escaping them: "\''
```

As you can see, the string representation used by Python still uses single quotes and a backslash to represent that last string.

Comment: To a complete Python noob like me it looks like the first variable contains a double quote (`"`) and the second one a single quote (`'`). These string should be different indeed? (Not my downvote.)

Comment: From the examples in the question it seems that one of the strings contains `'`, while the other contains `"`. The quoting part is clear.

Comment: Now the poster has fixed the question this answer makes sense.